# Error in the native query

Tags: java, sql, nativequery, sql-insert

Im new to sql and im facing a problem with the below native query

```
 public void saveOfflineBatchDetails(BigInteger user_id) {

    em.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO rst_offline_transaction_batch (created_date , user_id)" +
            "VALUES('?1', ?2)")
            .setParameter(1, new java.util.Date())
            .setParameter(2, user_id)
            .executeUpdate();
}
```

It doesn't pass the values to the database. the created date should be the today's date and time. Can anyone tell me whats wrong in this query.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally don't include the single quotes for parameterised queries. Try:

```
VALUES(?1, ?2)
```

(without the quotes around the `?1`). Otherwise it's hard (for both readers and parsers) to tell whether you wanted parameter 1 or the literal value `?1` to be inserted.

You should also check the return value from `executeUpdate()` to see if it thinks it affected any rows. This will probably give you zero but it's worth checking anyway.

And, finally, I think dates require special handling as per:

```
setParameter(1, new java.util.Date(), TemporalType.DATE);
```

This is because the Java Date object is not a date at all but a timestamp - you need to ensure you select the correct temporal object type so that the right value is placed in the query.

So, in short, something like:

```
int affected = em.createNativeQuery(
    "INSERT INTO rst_offline_transaction_batch (" +
    "    created_date," +     // ?1
    "    user_id" +           // ?2
    ") VALUES (?1,?2)"
    )
    .setParameter(1, new java.util.Date(), TemporalType.DATE)
    .setParameter(2, user_id)
    .executeUpdate();
// Check affected.
```

Comment: I tried but still it doesn't add the vales to the DB.I add single quotations cos its date.

Comment: @user421607: You don't need single quotes in a prepared statement, because the database engine will add them for you.

Comment: @paxdiablo: I don't think the type hinting is necessary, as the setParameter-function is overloaded for different types of values.

Comment: @nikc, true, but there's no two-argument overload for a date and, in any case, Java's dates are not dates, they're timestamps, so you're likely to end up with a parameter like `2011-01-02 15:36:74` rather than a usable date. In any case, I haven't checked my answer (I don't have a JEE environment handy at home), I may be completely wrong :-) My suggestion is for the OP to give it a shot.

Comment: @paxdiablo: How is that not a usable date? But I see your point and stand corrected.